# is there a way to present alternative front-end pages in a single instance of mean.js application

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I have an app, based on mean.js boiler plate.
This app has 5 distinctly different business functions.
I am now being asked to "brand" each of those functions separately.
Short of actually splitting this app into 5 different ones, is there a way to display a different front-end page based on the url that is requested?

Comment: I hope I have got your question correctly. Do you mean to say that your main page has various options and clicking on each option loads a main page for that option ?? If this is the case, then you can use Angular routing to achieve this.

Comment: Actually, what I needed was to have a few alternative landing pages, and load a specific one based on the request URL

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) . I think this is what you need. It lets you load different templates/pages based on the route . It is an Angular feature.

There is an alternative to ngRoute which is [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (third party module) which lets you have nested views. Go through both and select the one which suits you the best.